# Use MySQL connection in other class Java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to use the MySQL connection in an other class. My connection class:

```
public static Connection connect() {
    Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        if (con == null) {
            System.out.println("Connection cannot be established");
        }
        return con;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the other class: (just for test)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    MySQL db = new MySQL();
    db.connect();

    db.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");


}
```

It connects successfully to the MySQL server, but in the another class, I can only do db.connect(), and if I execute a Query, it says that the method doesn't exits in the MySQL class.

Comment: Look into connection pools.

Comment: When you call db.connect you are ignoring the return result, which is the Connection instance, which defines the executeQuery method, not the db class, in fact, you don't need create a new instance of MySQL as the connect method is static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.connect` returns a new `Connection` object, you should store that in a variable, and call `executeQuery` on it. This, what you posted, should not even compile. And you also should not call a static method as an object method. Make it non-static, or call it statically.

Comment: So, like this?  `MySQL db = new MySQL(); test = db.connect();`

Comment: yes: `Connection test = db.connect(); ... test.executeQuery();`

Answer (score 1):

basically `connect()` is  a static method . You should call it using class Name like `MySQL.connect()`